# SQL query: self-referencing foreign key relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables, `tabSparePart` and `tabSparePartCategory`. Every spare part belongs to a spare part category. I need all spare parts that belong to a specific category. But the problem is that a spare part category could be a "subcategory" of another, they reference each other (the "main categories" have 'null' in this FK column).

Let's say I need all spare parts with `fiSparePartCategory=1` and all spare parts that belong to a category that is a "subcategory" of `category=1`.

How to write the SQL query that returns all spare parts regardless of how many levels of subcategories there are. I hope you understand my requirement.

The following is an illustration of what I have. How to make it dynamic so that it works regardless of the number of subcategories?

Thanks, Tim

[image]

Link to image: http://www.bilder-hochladen.net/files/4709-lg-jpg.html

**EDIT**: Following is an other static approach which works when there is only one level of subcategory:

```
SELECT     SparePartName
FROM         tabSparePart
WHERE     (fiSparePartCategory IN
               (SELECT     idSparePartCategory
                     FROM          tabSparePartCategory
                     WHERE      (idSparePartCategory = 1) OR
                                (fiSparePartCategory = 1)))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [recursive Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) for this.

In your case, you would need to get all sparepart category ids for a specific main category id and join that with the spareparts. Something like this:

```
WITH SparePartCategories(CategoryId) AS
(
    SELECT c.idSparePartCategory
    FROM tabSparePartCategory c
    WHERE c.idSparePartCategory = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.idSparePartCategory
    FROM tabSparePartCategory c
    JOIN SparePartCategories parent ON c.fiSparePartCategory = parent.CategoryId
)
SELECT sp.SparePartName
FROM tabSparePart sp
JOIN SparePartCategories spc ON sp.fiSparePartCategory = spc.CategoryId
```

Comment: I made the SQL query somewhat better readable so that it's a little easier to understand.